# Is it possible for a regex to identify all equal value subarrays?

Tags: regex, sub-array

An equal value subarray is a subarray containing one or more consecutive elements of the same value.

For example, lets say our array is:

> 1,1,3

There are four equal value sub-arrays:

> [1], [1], [3], [1,1]

Note that elements can be part of more than one subarray.

I know `[\d]` matches digits, but this requirement is failing me. I am asking regex solution out of curiosity.

Comment: What is an equal value sub-array?

Comment: means all elements are same, and by subarray i mean either single element or consecutive elements. for example, [1,1,1,1] array has 10 such subarrays: 1 (len 4), 2 (len 3), 3 (len 2), and 4 (len 1).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with one regex. In fact, I recommend that you use more than one version of the string.

This regex should work:

```
^(\d+)(,\1){n}
```

I've made some adjustments to ensure a more robust regex:

- Allows for numbers greater than 10
- Will only match at the start, ensuring the count is not thrown off

For an array of length 4, you should replace `n` with `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`. This means that you will have to match against four regexes.

(Note that `n=0` is the same as `^(\d+)`)

Furthermore, you will have to "behead" the string, meaning that you would first match against `1,1,1,3` (new example) and then `1,1,3`, and then `1,3`, and then `3`.

Fun fact: you can use a regex to behead the string (group 1 will have the beheaded string):

```
^\d+,(.*)
```

(Obviously, you will need to ensure that you're not trying to behead an array of size 1.)

For an array of size 4, you will need to match against 4+3+2+1=**10** regexes.  You should test to see if the regex matched; if it did, you know to increment your count by 1. (Note that 10 is the maximum number of consecutive combinations for an array of 4.)

---

Here's an explanation of why you need to use more than one string. Take this regex:

```
(\d)(,?\1){n}
```

Again, `n` needs to be replaced. You would also need to use the `g` modifier (or its equivalent).

I'll use your example of `1,1,1,1`:

- `n=0` gives 4 matches [image]
- `n=1` gives 2 matches [image]
- `n=2` gives 1 match   [image]
- `n=3` gives 1 match   [image]

As you can see, it does not handle overlapping matches very well, because that's not how regex was designed.

Comment: @xploreraj I had some off by one errors (that I fixed). It doesn't work for all cases yet, either.

Comment: Yes, this is a good start. Helps a lot as well. Thanks Laurel. I am now myself hung after full days work. However, I am going to try all manipulations tomorrow on this. Certainly gonna work sometime.